# How change whole view without calling navigate()?

Tags: nativescript

1. I need dynamically change whole `view` to another (for example, root layout should be changed to `DockLayout`), but without using `Frame.navigate()` method.
   How do this?
2. Other question is about `View.load()` method. What use cases of this method?

```
const view = parse(`<StackLayout><Button tap="{{ onButtonTap }}" text="Tap me!"/></StackLayout>`);

class ViewModel extends Observable {

    public onButtonTap(args: EventData) {
        // need to change whole view to another here (for example, root layout should be DockLayout now)
        // but without using Frame.navigate() method
        // How do this?
    }
}

app.run({
    create: () => {
        view.bindingContext = new ViewModel();
        return view;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `builder` for that.

```
const builder = require('tns-core-modules/ui/builder');

const view = builder.parse(`<StackLayout><Button tap="{{ onButtonTap }}" text="Tap me!"/></StackLayout>`);
view.bindingContext = myBindingContext;

// If you want to replace everything in Page
page.content = view;

Or

// If you want to add it to a parent layout
parentStackLayout.addChild(view);
```

**Edit:** If you want to replace your root view itself, then you have to use the `_resetRootView` method on `application` module.

```
const create = () => {
    const view = builder.parse(`<StackLayout><Button tap="{{ onButtonTap }}" text="Tap me!"/></StackLayout>`);
    view.bindingContext = myBindingContext;
    return view;
};
application._resetRootView({
    create: create
});
```

Comment: in my example there are no `Page` element. Root is `StackLayout`. You show how create `View`. But I ask how dynamically change whole view, when it created and shown. And I know about `addChild`, question not about it, question about whole view.

Comment: As I said already in comment, just get your `StackLayout` reference, remove existing child and add new child.

Comment: One more time. Reference to `StackLayout` is `const view`. And I know about ability to remove and add child. But what about changing `StackLayout` to `DockLayout` (whole view).

Comment: You can't change a layout. But remove the DockLayout from your parent layout and add the new layout that is `const view`.

Comment: But what about if layout which I want remove don't have parent (because it's root)?

Comment: Use `_resetRootView` in that, answer is updated with sample code.

Comment: But what if by root view I mean root view of modal window?

Comment: Simple, just wrap your whole `DockLayout` with a `ContentView`. Use `contentViewRef.content = view`. This extra root view won't harm in anyway.